# Rolling time frame without temp tables

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000

I need to pull the sum of sales over a rolling 12 month time frame but my DBA did not give me the rights to make temp tables so I can not use those like I have seen in several posts when looking online. Also most of the most I find refer to using SQL 2012. Some of the servers I have to access are SQL 2000 some are SQL 2012 and I need this work on both. Here is so some sample code:

```
Select Rep
,Rep_ID
,Cast(Case when Sales_Date between '2/1/2014' and '1/31/2015' then Sum(Sales) else 0 end as decimal(18,2)) as "Sales Amount"

From dbo.Sales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're trying to get the sales amount for each representative over the past 12 months?

```
SELECT Rep
    ,Rep_ID
    ,"Sales Amount" = Sum(Sales)
FROM dbo.Sales
WHERE Sales_Date
    BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) -12, 0) 
        AND DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
GROUP BY Rep, Rep_ID
```

**EDIT:** Slight bugfix, the between dates are now 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 AND 2015-01-31 23:59:59.000

Comment: I tried this and I get the error Type Date is not a defined system type. This was the SQL 2000 server.

Comment: Maybe not cast to date then

Comment: I tried just removing the cast as date portion and the code runs but returns 0 results

Comment: So, dissect the query, see what part makes it not return results

Comment: It works without the where clause. It also works if I change the part after the and to just getdate(). so it appears there is an issue with the dateadd(day, -1,dateadd(month,datediff(month, getdate(),0),0)) portion but I don't really understand what this is doing. I have not used dateadd or datediff before.

Comment: Put select in front of it and see what it returns. It should return the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Select DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), 0), 0))  returns 1784-11-30 00:0000.000

Comment: Thank you for that fix this works perfect and I assume I can just change the -12 to like -6 for a 6 month time frame or -3 for a 3 month time frame

Comment: now I just need to read up on these terms you used I have not seen before so I can use them at will again